# Trouble getting heatmap charts to work with highcharts-vue

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm using the official [highcharts-vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) extension in my vue-3 project, and I have it working with the basic charts like [line](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) and [area](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic), but I'm having trouble getting a [heatmap](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap) chart to work. This chart differs in that it needs to be included as an imported module, which is where I suspect my problem lies.

This is what I'm doing in the parent component:

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<template>
  <HeatmapChart />
</template>

<script setup>
import HeatmapChart from 'src/components/charts/HeatmapChart.vue'
</script>
```

... and this is what's in the child HeatmapChart.vue file:

```html
<!-- HeatmapChart.vue -->
<template>
  <Highcharts :options="chartOptions" />
</template>

<script setup>
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HeatMap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap'

HeatMap(Highcharts)


const chartOptions =  {
   chart: {
     type: 'heatmap',
     ...
   }
   ...
}
</script>
```

Trying the above code doesn't render anything - the only feedback I get is the following console warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <Anonymous options=
```

I'm really not sure what's wrong, especially since I have other types of charts working. I'd sure appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official heatmap demo for Highcharts Vue Wrapper you can base on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8z2f5